# Elastic SIEM - alerting and correlation

Tags: elasticsearch, correlation

I was asked to do research, how can a very basic SIEM with Elastic Stack be build.
I managed to set up stack with Elasticsearch, Kibana and Beats, but now: How can I write correlation rules, like: If someone failed to log in 10 times in last 3 mins - ALERT. Or if there is unusual activity of scanning ports (detect nmap activity) - ALERT. How can it be done? Using only free options.

Answer (score 0):

Elastics free and open license allows the usage of detections.
Machine Learning is a paid feature but correlations (EQL) and normal detections (query) can be build. You also get to use the kibana interface to handle the signals into cases.

https://www.elastic.co/subscriptions